# Regarding .apk file size increment after Integrating paypal card

Tags: paypal

I am developing an Android application previously(Paypal without "io.card") it size was 2.3 MB after integrating paypal io.card it increases its siz to 15 MB. I need both the payment options(Paypal Account & Card payment) but i don't want card scanning feature. So, please kindly let me know how to remove card scanning feature to reduce the size of .apk. Or any other way to reduce the size of .apk with both payment options.

I have read the discussion at link below, but i didn't found solution.
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/93

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

refer this official Android SDK of paypal : [Paypal Android SDK GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) At this url, already mentioned that "How you remove only scanning feature.". In build.gradle of your app level "put packagingOptions ---- inside ----

```
    android{ .... 
             .....
             packagingOptions{}
             .......
    }
```